# How to import standard library instead of same-named module in module path

Tags: python, import, python-2.7, naming-conventions

I have the following directory structure

```
main_code.py
libs/
    __init__.py
    mylib.py
    time.py
```

with `main_code.py` just importing `mylib`:

```
from libs import mylib
```

and `mylib.py` just importing `time`:

```
import time
print time
```

Now it turns out that `mylib.py` imports `libs/time.py` and *not* the built-in standard library `time`. Is there any way to get the 'normal' behavior, i.e. that `mylib.py` imports the built-in standard library `time`, *without* changing `time.py`? Is this the 'normal' behavior anyway? Do I have to rename `time.py`? Are there any style guide recommendations more than PEP8 on that issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add at the top of `mylib.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

See [Rationale for Absolute Imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports).