# First Python Package: Modules aren't loading

Tags: python-2.7, package

### Background:

Apparently my question regarding the best ways to build an autoloader in Python was too broad (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678974/python-autoloader). Not sure why...

I had hoped to get a few code snippets to make my life easier with regards to choosing between importing modules or building a package. But not so much. So I decided to try to build a package of python functions meant to emulate PHP functions such str_replace.

I've named the package p2p and the directory structure is like this:

```
lib/p2p
  setup.py
  CHANGES.txt
  MANIFEST.IN
  README.txt
  /bin (empty)
  /docs (empty)
  /p2p
    __init__.py
    /str
      __init__.py
      str.py
    /time
      __init__.py
      time.py
    /json
      __init__.py
      json.py
    /utils
      __init__.py
      utils.py
```

The `__init__.py` are all empty.

### In the Console:

Now when I build the package (`python setup.py install`) I get no errors. When I `import p2p` I get no errors. However, when I try to use `p2p.time.timeID()` I get:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timeID'

When I type `p2p.time` I get:

> module 'p2p.time' from '/home/gabe/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/p2p/time/**init**.pyc'

I've Googled the attribute error and spent most of yesterday reading up on how to create a python package. What am I doing wrong? (Ultimately this appears like it would have been easier with simple modules and an autoloader. I'm not sure how to build an autoloader that will properly import the modules, due to relative path restrictions in Python, without just dumping my entire library directory structure into the path.)

### lib/p2p/setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='p2p',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='Me',
    author_email='me@example.com',
    packages=['p2p', 'p2p.test', 'p2p.str', 'p2p.time', 'p2p.json', 'p2p.utils'],
    package_dir={'p2p':'p2p', 'str':'p2p/str'},
    scripts=[],
    url='',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='PHP to Python functions.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "",
    ],
)
```

### lib/p2p/p2p/time/time.py

```
import time

# http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.microtime/
def timeID():
    return time.time()
```

### Notes:

- Ubuntu 14.04 Dekstop
- Anaconda with Python 2.7
- Spyder
- I'm a complete Python Noob but have worked in PHP and Ruby for a couple of years now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> p2p/time/time.py

Well there you go. You want `p2p.time.time.timeID` instead. Or you could just put it in `p2p/time/__init__.py` instead.

Comment: I had hoped you were correct. However, I get the same error with `timeID` replaced by `time`. That said if I want the structure to be `p2p.time.timeID()` you suggest putting `timeID()` into `__init__.py`. Can I also simply move `time.py` up to the `/lib/p2p/p2p` directory? Get rid of the str, time, json, and utils directories all together...

Comment: You can move `time.py` up one level and get rid of `time/` if you want to use `p2p.time.timeID()` instead.

Comment: I've tried that now as well and it also isn't working. However, if I use `from p2p.time import time as t2` then I can call `t2.timeID()` and get a new error about time not having the attribute time (sounds the same but points to a different point in code). So I changed the `import time` at the top of `time.py` to `import time as t`. But still seeing the no attribute issue...

Comment: That's a [completely different problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477040/how-to-import-standard-library-instead-of-same-named-module-in-module-path).

Comment: Thanks for the link for the time problem. Before seeing your comment I'd thought maybe the issue was naming. So I had already mangled my directory and file name to test it. I can now get to timeID via `from p2p.timeTools import tools as t2` where the `time` directory became `timeTools` and `time.py` became `tools.py`. However, the behavior is the same for the str module. I can get to it via `from p2p.str import str as s2` and then `s2.str_replace()`. But I can't get there via simple `import p2p` and `p2p.str.str.str_replace()`.

Comment: *Also* [a different problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274499/specificity-in-importing-python-module/25274605#25274605).

Comment: Thanks, the `p2p.str.str.str_replace()` started working after I'd used `import p2p.str as s3`. If I understand this correctly it didn't seem to import the child modules. I'd like to vote for your answer but it is incomplete, can you incorporate these comments into it? Specifically, I think the issue is stemming from my have `str.py` under the `str` directory. And str appears to be a reserved word - Spyder shows str in green just like does `import` and `as`. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: It isn't a reserved word (since then your code wouldn't work at all), but it is the name of a built-in type and should be avoided.